# Spring mockito bean still does nothing, despite doAnswer setting

Tags: spring, testing, mocking, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to stub an injected dependency upon its void method:

```
@Autowired
private FeedbackService service;
@MockBean
private MailSender sender;

@Test
public void testMonitor() {
    // mocking MailSender#sendMessage
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        log.info("SUBJECT: {}", invocation.getArgument(0, String.class));
        log.info("CONTENT: {}", invocation.getArgument(1, String.class));
        for (String dest : (String[]) invocation.getArgument(2)) {
            log.info("DEST: {}", dest);
        }
        return null;    // Void anyway
    }).when(sender).sendMessage(anyString(), anyString(), any(String[].class)); //FIXME still doNothing
    // invoking the service which calls MailSender#sendMessage
    service.monitor();
}
```

But logging and debugging shows that no interception occurs at runtime.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong, please ?

The casting of string arrays seems to be trickier than I thought. This works as an interceptor:

```
.sendMessage(anyString(), anyString(), any());
```

But the third argument arrives as a String instead of a string array.
NB: **that third parameter is a vararg** but #anyVararg won't work either.

Comment: With **what** is the `sendMessage` method being called? Please show that code? Is any of the parameters `null`? If so `anyString()` etc. won't work you need to use `nullable(String.class)` instead.

Comment: no arguments are null in this case

Comment: As stated please show the code that is calling this method, as well as the signature of the `sendMessage` method.

Comment: There you are:  void sendMessage(String subject, String text, String... to);
it is actually an ellipse, though

Comment: varargs isn't an array, hence it doesn't match hence no interception. In the interceptionyou could use `getArguments` and just print them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out that even if the compiler would allow varargs to be treated as arrays, the invocation arguments would still consider arguments as separated entities.

```
@Test
public void testMonitor() {
    // mocking MailSender#sendMessage
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        log.info("SUBJECT: {}", invocation.getArgument(0, String.class));
        log.info("CONTENT: {}", invocation.getArgument(1, String.class));
        for (int i = 2; i < invocation.getArguments().length; i++) {
            log.info("DEST: {}", (String) invocation.getArgument(i));
        }
        return null;    // Void
    }).when(sender)
      .sendMessage(anyString(), anyString(), (String[]) any());
    // invoking the service, depending on the above stub
    service.monitor();
}
```